# R parallel computing by doSNOW package, processes registered but not consuming CPU cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using the doSNOW package on my desktop.

```
cl <- makeCluster(6, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
m <- matrix(rnorm(90000), 30000, 3)
foreach(i=1:nrow(m), .combine=rbind) %dopar% (m[i,] / mean(m[i,]))
stopCluster(cl)
```

When the above program is running, I opened the Window Task Manager, and in the Processes tab I saw there are 5 or 6 new-created processes named "Rscript.exe", but only one of them is running.

I am using my office desktop. I remember the first time I used "doSNOW" on my own laptop, Windows popped out a small dialogue bar asking some kind of permission, but my office desktop never asked me that. I don't know if my situation has something to do with some system block, just a note here.

Many thanks in advance to whom can help me.

Sincerely
Charlie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the tasks are too small. The one process that appeared to be running was probably the master combining all 30,000 results.

If you have many tiny tasks, you should group them together into fewer, larger tasks, which is called *chunking*. Here's one way to do that for your example:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(itertools)
cl <- makeCluster(6, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
m <- matrix(rnorm(90000), 30000, 3)

foreach(s=isplitRows(m, chunks=getDoParWorkers()), .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  t(apply(s, 1, function(x) x / mean(x)))
}
```

On my MacBook Pro, this runs over 70 times faster than your version. You could probably solve this particular problem faster using something like Rcpp, but the technique is very important, and at least it won't appear that only one process is doing any work.